# iphone uitable grid view - drag and drop cell content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Here my requirement is to drag a cell content (i.e.. like uiimageview or a uiview, uibutton any) to another cell.

Basically the tableview should be in a grid structure.

a simple example is table should be like apple's bookshelf and it should be drag-able like  drag and drop the book to different cells..

can anyone help me how to implement it and any idea and suggestion will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start with `UIGestureRecognisers` attached to the views you want to move around. Specifically `UIPanGestureRecogniser`. Something like this:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
[panGestureRecognizer release];
```

...

```
-(void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) panGesture {
switch (panGesture.state) { 
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            UIView *view = panGesture.view;
            CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:view];
            [view setCenter:CGPointMake(view.center.x + translation.x, view.center.y + translation.y)];
            [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:view];
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: 
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Basically, the pan gesture has a location and tracks movement, and you pass this onto the centre property of your `UIView` which moves it around.

You might define particular frames as drop points, and if the gesture ends at certain points animate the `UIView` to the nearest cell (in `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`).

Comment: Ok, post some code of what you have tried exactly that isn't working. What you problems are you experiencing?